# Android double tap slide zoom

Tags: android-maps, zooming

Google Maps has a one finger zoom capability by double tapping and without lifting the finger slide up to zoom in and slide down to zoom out.

Is this possible for other map type apps? Are there any code examples out there for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tap, hold + up/down` zoom is implemented in [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/index), so it is available to any application, which uses that.

Zero lines of code required.

Answer (score 0):

I created something to do this on iOS and released it on [GitHub](https://github.com/bddckr/BDDROneFingerZoomGestureRecognizer).

The actual tap recognition is easy, calculating the "correct" (whatever feels "correct") `zoomScale` is the problem… Have a look at [this](https://github.com/bddckr/BDDRScrollViewAdditions/blob/master/BDDRScrollViewAdditions/UIScrollView+BDDRScrollViewAdditions.m) to see how it is used.

You can probably use the same logic on Android (I have no experience with Android).